# How to integrate Dynamics CRM 2015 on-premise API using PHP and create leads

Tags: php, rest, api, soap, dynamics-crm

I am creating a web application in php, in that I need to integrate with Dynamics CRM 2015 on-premise API. Currently our CRM not using any authentication(not using ADFS). I have the following code which returns me some xml/array. But I am not sure if this is the expected output. It is returning only 'OrganizationData.svc'.

```
// The host name of the on-premises dynamics instance
$host = 'crm.mycompany.com';
$organization = 'MyCompany';
$crm_url = "http://$host/$organization/";

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$url = $crm_url . 'XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/SystemUserSet';
$ch = curl_init();
 $headers = array(
      'Method: GET',
      'Connection: keep-alive',
      'User-Agent: PHP-SOAP-CURL',
      'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'Accept: application/json',
      'Host: ' . $host);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$response=json_decode($response, true);

print_r($response);
```

Microsoft has given APIs to create: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt770366.aspx , and retrive: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607871.aspx . but I am confused how do I use that?

Can someone please help me. I am new to API integration. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Please refer to this link. [Answer on this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215067/trying-to-create-lead-in-dynamic-crm-using-api-in-php?noredirect=1#comment69630624_41215067)

Answer (score 1):

So the apis that you have linked to are the new web api which is different then the old 2011 enpoint which you are using in your example. The web api (if I remember correctly) is in a preview form in 2015 and is incomplete. The documentation for the 2011 endpoint which can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767(v=crm.7).aspx). We could never quite get an external client to authenticate to CRM so if you can figure it out please let us know. How we implemented the crm integration with some of our non-microsoft systems is we used a small asp.net page that then used the [crm client tooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.aspx) to communicate with CRM on behalf of that application.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can successfully authenticate to crm through api now I am trying to create leads through api but getting 400 error. Please help!

Comment: @pk27 Which API are you using and what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I am using the API mentioned [here] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767(v=crm.7).aspx) . By this I am getting the all leads but can't create it through API. Getting 400 html code error. Please see my this [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215067/trying-to-create-lead-in-dynamic-crm-using-api-in-php)

Comment: @pk27 There should also be a response that tells you what is wrong with the request. Is there a reason that you are using the SOAP api and not the REST api?